# Tomcat no funciona

Tags: tomcat

Estoy intentando ejecutar el servidor tomcat en windows, lo ejecuto y aparece esto en el navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la terminal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que le puede pasar, las variables de entorno parecen estar bien definidas y parece que no da ningún problema directamente.
Ayuda pls

Comment: El servidor arranca perfectamente, tal y como te pone en la última línea de la captura del terminal. De hecho, la respuesta que ves en el navegador te la da el mismo servidor Tomcat. Otra cosa es si tienes aplicaciones ya desplegadas y a qué aplicación estás intentando acceder

Comment: Es que la dirección es localhoost:8080, la cual se supone que siempre ha de estar disponible

Comment: Y lo está pero no muestra nada, que es lo que corresponde. Si quieres que entrando a la raíz del Tomcat te vaya a alguna aplicación tienes que configurarlo pero necesitas tener alguna aplicación desplegada

Comment: ¿Qué URL estás usando para acceder al servidor? Tiene pinta de que has borrado el directorio `webapps/ROOT` o bien que lo que tengas como `ROOT.war` no proporcione una página web por defecto o bien en la URL estás proporcionando el nombre de un archivo que no está desplegado.